# ¿Cómo asignar valores a un Array en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy tratando de hacer un arreglo que me acomode ítems por columna. Quiero que quede algo asi:

```
  var arr = []
    var NodeListArray1=[div.no-visible, div.no-visible, div.no-visible, div.no-visible]

    var NodeListArray2=[div, div, div]

    arr=[
    div.no-visible,div,
    div.no-visible,div,
    div.no-visible,div
    ]
```

Tengo un loop que me acomoda mis items en el arreglo de esta manera:

```
arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
newArr = [];

for(var c = 1; c < 4; c++){
   for(var r = 0; r < 3; r++){
     newArr.push((3*r) + c);
   }
}
 resultado:[1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9];
```

Pero no logro poder meter mis nodos y que me los muestre en ese orden. ¿hay alguna solucion para esto?

Answer (score 0):

No se si entendi el problema, necesitas un array que quede exactamente en este orden?

```
arr=[
  div.no-visible,div,
  div.no-visible,div,
  div.no-visible,div
]
```

Para ordenarlos puede que este ejemplo te sirva:

```js
array1=[1,3,5];
array2=[2,4,6];

for(let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
  array2.splice(i+i,0,array1[i]);
}

console.log(array2);
```

Tambien intente hacerlo con tus elementos del array:

```js
var NodeListArray1=['div.no-visible', 'div.no-visible', 'div.no-visible', 'div.no-visible']

var NodeListArray2=['div', 'div', 'div']

for(let i = 0; i < NodeListArray1.length; i++){
  NodeListArray2.splice(i+i,0,NodeListArray1[i]);
}

console.log(NodeListArray2);
```

De nuevo, no se si eso es lo que necesitabas, pero de todas formas el metodo [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice) te puede servir!